# If the target of Final Rebuke ends the forced move in a square adjacent to a solid obstacle, do they take the extra damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, forced-movement

The power in question is Final Rebuke, a Paladin level 9 power from *Divine Powers*:

> Daily • Divine, Reliable, Weapon
>   Standard Action
>   Melee weapon
>   **Target**: One creature
>   **Attack**: Strength vs. Fortitude
>   **Hit**: 2 [W] + Strength modifier damage, and you push the target 5 squares. If the target ends this movement in a square adjacent to a solid obstacle, the target takes 1 [W] extra damage.

Legend: The `B` is the user of the attack, `E` the target, the `O` is a wall, and the `X`s are empty squares.

When you use and hit with the attack:

```
XXXXXXOX
BEXXXXXO
XXXXXXXXO
```

… then the target ends his/her forced movement but does not hit the wall:

```
XXXXXXOX
BXXXXXEO
XXXXXXXXO
```

… will the target take the 1[W] extra damage or not?

And then will it work if the solid obstacle is to the left and/or right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Adjacent*, aside from the standard english definition of "next to", has defined rules, as per page 201 of the Rules Compendium:

> **Adjacent Squares:** Two squares are adjacent is a side or corner of one touches a side of corner of the other. Two creatures or objects are adjacent if one of them is in a square adjacent to a square occupied or filled by the other, or if they are in the same square.

In your example, the target *would* take the extra 1[W] damage because they are adjacent to the squares of a solid object.